# Identify website URL hit from withing website pages or directly from browser address bar

Tags: coldfusion, iis-8

Basically we have to implement logic to identify URL access from outside or internal website pages.
if outside than redirect to latest product detail, if it is from internal website pages than display clicked product detail.

**Note: For both cases URL should be same and not to add extra query parameters.**

**Approach used to solve :**

We have used form submit for internal URL but one drawback of using solution that browser back button not work.

Please suggest any solution.

Thanks

Comment: For the page where products are selected, add a variable to the anchor tag that indicates that the user is on your site.  Then, on the next page, base your logic on the presence of that variable.

Answer (score 3):

There are two primary ways to deal with this situation where you want certain users to have a different result without otherwise changing the page url.

- cgi.remote_addr - if you want everyone internal to an office network for example to see a different page than those outside the network then you can check the IP address of the user
- cgi.http_referer - if you want everyone coming from a specific page (ex: admin page, intranet, etc) then can check from where they clicked from

Neither of these approaches should be used for standalone security purposes as they can be spoofed.